# How to do a registerform by ASP.NET VB SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I am designing a registerform by vb.net but I don't know how to do this.
The following is my code:

```html
Protected Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("localdb\v11.0")
        Conn.Open()
        Dim sqlstr As String = "insert into user_profile(username,password,nickname,realname,email) values('&username.Text&','&password.Text&','&nickname.Text&','&realname.Text&','&email.Text&')"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, Conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Cancel()
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

but there is some errors...
and, is this concept right? If click the button then insert the data into SQL database?

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: there is an ArgumentException.
the statement:Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("localdb\v11.0")

Answer (score 0):

```html
Protected Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
        Dim Conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("localdb\v11.0")
        Conn.Open()
        Dim sqlstr As String = "insert into user_profile(username, password, nickname, realname, email) values('" & username.Text & "','" & password.Text & "','" & nickname.Text & "','" & realname.Text & "','" & email.Text &"')"
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sqlstr, Conn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Cancel()
        Conn.Close()
        Conn.Dispose()
    End Sub
```

You need to build your sqlstr correctly ... use quotes to separate the string from values of text boxes. You are also open to sql injections you should use paramaterised values.

Comment: Has my suggestion worked? Can you see why you were getting a Sql exception? You needed to create your string correctly. e.g.